# tic tac toe game (js)

Tags: javascript, html, function, logic

i'm making a tic tac toe game using html/css/js and i have a problem with my tie option, i have 2 problems with it, 
1: if one of the players win in the last turn it still shows tie
2: even if it is a tie in the end and i keep pressing the buttons the 'X' changes to 'O' which it shouldnt.
there is a move board which updates also by the tie value (but its not relevent to my problem).
how can i fix those issues?

my html:

```
<body onload="startGame();">
    <h1>Tic tac toe</h1>
    <div id="message"></div>
      <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="square1" class ="square" onclick = "nextMove(this);"></td>
            <td id="square2" class ="square" onclick = "nextMove(this);"></td>
            <td id="square3" class ="square" onclick = "nextMove(this);"></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td id="square4" class ="square" onclick = "nextMove(this);"></td>
            <td id="square5" class ="square" onclick = "nextMove(this);"></td>
            <td id="square6" class ="square" onclick = "nextMove(this);"></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td id="square7" class ="square" onclick = "nextMove(this);"></td>
            <td id="square8" class ="square" onclick = "nextMove(this);"></td>
            <td id="square9" class ="square" onclick = "nextMove(this);"></td>
        </tr>   

      </table>
    <div id="moves">
        <p id = "one"></p>
        <p id = "two"></p>
        <p id = "tree"></p>
        <p id = "four"></p>
        <p id = "five"></p>
        <p id = "six"></p>
        <p id = "seven"></p>
        <p id = "eight"></p>
        <p id = "nine"></p>
    </div>
```

and js:

```
var tie = 0;
var move = 0;
var  lastMove;
var oneOne = false;
function startGame(){
    for(var i =1; i < 10 ; i++){ //clears all squares
        clearBox(i)
    }
    clearMoves(); //clears move board
    tie=0;  
    move = 0;
    document.turn = "X";  //50% that x will start (explanation on the next line)

    if(Math.random() < 0.5){ //50% that o will start
        document.turn = "O";
    }
    document.winner = null;
    setMessage(document.turn + " gets to start");
}

function setMessage(msg){
        document.getElementById("message").innerText = msg;

}

function setMoves(num){
        if(num == 1)    
            document.getElementById("one").innerText = "player " + document.turn + " selected " + lastMove + " tie: " + tie+ "one"+ oneOne;
        else if (num == 2)
            document.getElementById("two").innerText = "player " + document.turn + " selected " + lastMove+ " tie: " + tie+"one"+ oneOne;
        else if (num == 3)
            document.getElementById("tree").innerText = "player " + document.turn + " selected " + lastMove+ "tie:" + tie+"one"+ oneOne;
        else if (num == 4)
            document.getElementById("four").innerText = "player " + document.turn + " selected " + lastMove+ "tie:" + tie+"one"+ oneOne;
        else if (num == 5)
            document.getElementById("five").innerText = "player " + document.turn + " selected " + lastMove+ "tie:" + tie+"one"+ oneOne;
        else if (num == 6)
            document.getElementById("six").innerText = "player " + document.turn + " selected " + lastMove+ "tie:" + tie+"one"+ oneOne;
        else if (num == 7)
            document.getElementById("seven").innerText = "player " + document.turn + " selected " + lastMove+ "tie:" + tie+"one"+ oneOne;
        else if (num == 8)
            document.getElementById("eight").innerText = "player " + document.turn + " selected " + lastMove+ "tie:" + tie+"one"+ oneOne;
        else if (num == 9 && document.winner != null)
            document.getElementById("nine").innerText = "player " + document.turn + " selected " + lastMove+ "tie:" + tie+"one"+ oneOne;


}

function clearMoves()  //clear all fields
{   
        document.getElementById("one").innerText = "";
        document.getElementById("two").innerText = "";
        document.getElementById("tree").innerText = "";
        document.getElementById("four").innerText = "";
        document.getElementById("five").innerText = "";
        document.getElementById("six").innerText = "";
        document.getElementById("seven").innerText = "";
        document.getElementById("eight").innerText = "";
        document.getElementById("nine").innerText = "";
}

function nextMove(square){
    move++;
    if(square.innerText == "" && document.winner == null){
        tie++;
    }
    lastMove = square.id;

    if (document.winner == null && tie > 8){
        setMessage("its a tie");
        square.innerText = document.turn;
    }
    else if(document.winner != null){ //game over someone won
        setMessage(document.winner + " already won the game, please start over");
    }
    else if(square.innerText == ""){   //square not used
        square.innerText = document.turn;
        switchTurn();
    }else{
        setMessage("That square is already used!");
    }
    if (document.winner == null && move < 10){ //update move board
        setMoves(tie);
    }

}


function switchTurn(){
    if(tie == 9){
        setMessage("tie");
    }
    else if(checkForWinner(document.turn)){
        setMessage(document.turn + " Won!!!");
        document.winner = document.turn;
    }
    else if(document.turn == "X" && tie != 9){
        document.turn = "O";
        setMessage("its " + document.turn + " turn");
    }else{
        document.turn = "X";
        setMessage("its " + document.turn + " turn");
    }

}

function clearBox(number){
    document.getElementById("square" + number).innerText = "";
}

function checkForWinner(move){
    var result = false;
    if(checkRow(1,2,3,move) || checkRow(4,5,6,move) || checkRow(7,8,9,move) //rows
        ||  checkRow(1,4,7,move) || checkRow(2,5,8,move) || checkRow(3,6,9,move) //cols
        ||  checkRow(1,5,9,move) || checkRow(3,5,7,move)){ //diagonal
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}

function checkRow(a, b, c, move){
    var result = false;
    if(getBox(a) == move && getBox(b) == move && getBox(c) == move)
        result = true;
    return result;

}

function getBox(number){
    return document.getElementById("square" + number).innerText;
}
```

thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to return on these checks. If that first `if conditional` consists of a completed action, return inside of it. Otherwise you will continue to do checks.

Before a move is made, you should check to see if the game is over and return if so. That should solve problems for

> Even if it is a tie in the end and i keep pressing the buttons the 'X' changes to 'O' which it shouldn't..

The overall check before moving should help prevent a lot of issues and javascript requires strict returns to exit.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below basic tic tac toe game built using javascript,

```
//HTML
<div id="table">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
<div>
  <button onClick="clearCells()">clear</button>
</div>
<div id="message">  
</div>

//CSS
#table{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:50px 50px 50px;
  row-gap:2px;
  column-gap:2px;
}

#table div{
  padding:10px;
  background-color:blue;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  height: 20px;
}

//JAVASCRIPT
var tabEle = document.getElementById("table");
var msgEle = document.getElementById("message"); 

var newArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tabEle.children);

var clickCount = 0;
var isBingo=false;

newArr.forEach(ele=>{
ele.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{eventHandler(e)})
})

function eventHandler(e){
 if(!e.target.innerText){
   clickCount++;
   if(clickCount%2!=0){
   e.target.innerText="X"
   }else{
   e.target.innerText="O";
   }
   checkBingo(e);
 }
}

function checkBingo(e){
 let cindex = newArr.indexOf(e.target);
 let match = [[0,1,2],[0,3,6],[0,4,8],[1,4,7],[2,4,6],[2,5,8],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]];
 
 let filteredMatch = match.filter(ar=>{
 return ar.includes(cindex);
 })
 
 filteredMatch.forEach(ele=>{
 if((newArr[ele[0]].innerText === newArr[ele[1]].innerText) && (newArr[ele[1]].innerText=== newArr[ele[2]].innerText)){
 success(ele[0], ele[1], ele[2])
 }else{
 draw()
 }
 })
}

function success(...ar){
ar.forEach((n)=>{
 newArr[n].style.cssText="color:red"
})
msgEle.innerText=`${newArr[ar[0]].innerText} has won`;
isBingo=true;
setTimeout(clearCells,5000);
}

function clearCells(){
clickCount=0;
isBingo=false;
msgEle.innerText="";
newArr.forEach(ar=>{
ar.innerText="";
ar.style.cssText="color:white"
})
}

function draw(){
var allCellsFilled = newArr.every(ele=>{
return ele.innerText!="";
})
if(allCellsFilled && !isBingo){
 msgEle.innerText="Draw match";
 setTimeout(clearCells,3000)
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var picArray=["circle.png","cross.png"]; // for storing images of cross 
 and circle
var winArray = 
 "123","132","213","231","321","312","456","465","546","564","645","654","789","798","897","879","987","978","147","174","417","471","714","741","258","285","825","852","528","582","396","369","639","693","936","963","159","195","915","951","591","519","357","375","537","573","735","753"];
// stores all possible test cases on which the user wins
var clicked_button_zero=[]; // stores the numerical ID of the image 
button of zero button
var clicked_button_one=[]; //stores the numerical ID of the image button 
having of cross button
var clicked=[]; //stores which places are already clicked
var i=1;
function change(id) //called upon the clicking of the buttons
{
 if($.inArray(id,clicked)==-1 ) //checks whether it has been clicked 
or not
 {
 //If not clicked then it enters this block
  if(i==0)
  {
   i=1;
   var temp=id.substr(3,4);
   clicked_button_one.push(temp);
   clicked.push(id);
  }
  else if(i==1)
  {
   i=0;
   var temp=id.substr(3,4);
   clicked_button_zero.push(temp);
   clicked.push(id);
  }
  $("#"+id).attr("src",picArray[i]);
  $("#"+id).attr("value",i);      
  checkArray();
 }
 else 
 {
//If clicked then it enters this block
   alert("This has been marked");
 }
 }
 
function checkArray() //for checking whether it is win or loss
{
 var subset_zero = combination(clicked_button_zero);
    //array for storing all combinations of the values present having 
     value 0
 var subset_one=combination(clicked_button_one);
    //array for storing all combinations of the values present having 
     value 1
 var flag1=check(subset_zero); 
 var flag2=check(subset_one);
 if(flag1==1)
 {
  alert("0 wins");
  location.reload(); //reloads the webpage
 }
 if(flag2==1)
 {
  alert("1 wins");
  location.reload();
 }
}
function check(arr) //it checks the array 'arr' against 'winArray'
{
 var i;
 for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
 {
  if($.inArray(arr[i],winArray)!=-1)
  {
   return 1;
  }
 }
}

function combination (arr) //returns all possible combination of values
{

  let i, j, temp
  let result = []
  let arrLen = arr.length
  let power = Math.pow
  let combinations = power(2, arrLen)
     
  for (i = 0; i < combinations;  i++) {
    temp = ''
    
    for (j = 0; j < arrLen; j++) {
      if ((i & power(2, j))) {
        temp += arr[j]
      }
    }
    result.push(temp)
  }
  return result;
}
```

```css
button{
 width:200px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 height:50px;
}
img{
 height:220px;
 width:220px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>
  Tic Tac Toe
 </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <center>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><img src="question.png" id="img1" onclick="change(this.id)"></td>
    <td><img src="question.png" id="img2" onclick="change(this.id)"></td>
    <td><img src="question.png" id="img3" onclick="change(this.id)"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><img src="question.png" id="img4" onclick="change(this.id)"></td>
    <td><img src="question.png" id="img5" onclick="change(this.id)"></td>
    <td><img src="question.png" id="img6" onclick="change(this.id)"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><img src="question.png" id="img7" onclick="change(this.id)"></td>
    <td><img src="question.png" id="img8" onclick="change(this.id)"></td>
    <td><img src="question.png" id="img9" onclick="change(this.id)"></td>
   </tr>

  </table>
  
  <button onclick="location.reload()">Reset</button>
 </center>
 </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.